# What does rsync status code 3072 mean?

Tags: ssh, rsync, git, static-files

I'm using the static site generator Nanoc, with rsync locally and on the (ancient Ubuntu) server so I can deploy from the command line.

It's been awhile since I last used rsync for this site but I'm now getting:

`Nanoc::Extra::Piper::Error: command exited with a nonzero status code 3072 (command: rsync --group --links --perms --partial --progress --recursive --times --verbose --compress --exclude=".hg" --exclude=".svn" --exclude=".git" output/ uname@IP_ADDRESS:/home/path_to_remote_dir)`

Locally I was running rsync 2.6.9 (when the error occurred) so upgraded rsync to 3.1.3_1 (OS X/Homebrew). The server runs rsync 3.0.3.

Is that 3072 error code from rsync? If so, what does it mean?

---

### Update Feb 2020

After even more rsync issues deploying this [Nanoc](https://nanoc.ws/) site I've moved to setting up GIT for `nanoc deploy`:

- copy the SSH key from the server `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server`
- create a bare GIT repo on the server (outside the site root)
- set up `deploy` in "nanoc.yaml" (as below)
- exclude "output/" from the nanoc site repo in local ".gitignore"
- `git init` *inside* the "output" and…
- …`git remote set-url server ssh://USER@IP:PORT/PATH_TO_BARE_REPO.git`
- create a ".git/hooks/post-receive" file inside the bare repo (as below)
- make it executable with `chmod +x post-receive`

**in "nanoc.yaml":**

```
deploy:
  default:
    kind: git
    remote: ssh://USER@IP:PORT/PATH_TO_BARE_REPO.git
    branch: master
    forced: true
```

(to only overwrite changed files, I might try using without "forced", but it's pretty quick for what is a large site anyway)

**On the server in "SITE_REPO.git/hooks/post-receive":**

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/PATH_TO_SITE_ROOT --git-dir=PATH_TO_BARE_REPO.git checkout -f
```

And it works fine. So in this case, I think GIT is a better option here. I also created a global `git pushall` alias on my local system to push to the server and the live site with one command.

Answer (score 2):

I found someone reported this Sync Tool error 3072 a year ago, and the logs were showing nothing except an unauthorized login failure. Check for password changes.